# Test that Sidekiq job called mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm testing my Sidekiq job and I'm trying to figure out how to ensure that it called a method within the job with the correct arguments. Here is my actual job:

#### JOB:

```
def perform
  csv = Campaign.to_csv
  email = current_sso_user.email

  CampaignMailer.send_csv(email, csv).deliver_now
end
```

I'd like to build a test that ensures the CampaignMailer.send_csv was called with the correct args.

Here is what I have currently:

#### TEST:

```
RSpec.describe CampaignsExortJob, type: :model do
  subject(:job) { CampaignsExportJob.new }

  describe '#perform' do
    let(:campaign) { create(:campaign) }

    it 'sends the csv email' do
      expect(job).to receive(:CampaignMailer.send_csv)
    end
  end
end
```

But this is a syntax error. Can anyone give me some guidance on how to test this properly? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the rspec docs(https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/expect-message-using-should-receive):

expect a message with an argument
Given
a file named "spec/account_spec.rb" with:

```
require "account"
require "spec_helper"

describe Account do
  context "when closed" do
    it "logs an account closed message" do
      logger = double("logger")
      account = Account.new logger

      logger.should_receive(:account_closed).with(account)

      account.close
    end
  end
end
```

And
a file named "lib/account.rb" with:

```
Account = Struct.new(:logger) do
  def close
    logger.account_closed(self)
  end
end
```

When
I run rspec spec/account_spec.rb
Then
the output should contain "1 example, 0 failures"

so in your case:

```
CampaignMailer.should_receive(:send_csv).with(<expected_email_arg>, <expected_csv_arg>)
```

You can also add on a `.and_return(<expected_return_value>)` to test the return value.